# How to return the value of a certain cell using other cells as variables?

Tags: excel

I've built a pricing model in Excel that returns in cell E1 the average price across many vendors, pricing options, etc., for varying Products (defined in cell E4) and Quantities (defined in cell E2).

In creating cost sheets, however, I have to plug in each possible quantity into E2 and product into E4, then manually copy (or type) the returned average price from E1 into the table.

I'm thinking there must be a way for me to fill the table with what would be the value of E1 if E2 were equal to X and E4 were equal to Y, where X and Y are each the Quantity and Product defined in columns of the table.

For example, I have:

***Column A | Col B. | Col. C | Col. D*

Universe | Qnty. | Product | Price**

Universe A | 1,000 | Prod 1 | ???
Universe B | 5,000 | Prod 2 | ???
Universe C | 3,000 | Prod 2 | ???

Essentially I want to turn cells E2 and E4 into variables and have a column on the table return "value of $E$1 when $E$2=B1 and $E$4=C1", rather than manually entering each quantity and product.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite follow your logic. Can you put your model/calculations in a separate worksheet, then pull in the returned average price for each product back into the main sheet?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time putting this in words.

The model runs a bunch of vlookup and index functions to find the lowest prices of the product and quantity specified for a few vendors, then averages those prices and returns the average. In a separate sheet, I have a table of quantities and products. I need to find what value would be returned in my model for the quantities and products in the table and append them to the table.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what is in Sheet1, Sheet2, etc.? I am trying to figure out, can you have E1 lookup/index values in Sheet2 to find the right data? Or do you need to have a Sheet3 that calculates based on your model in Sheet2, and then return that value to E1 in Sheet1?

Comment: A quantity is entered in E2 (could be any number >1000) and a product entered in E4 (one of a few product codes). Based on these values, there are 7 separate costs (Printing, Data, Shipping, etc) that are calculated via lookups/indexes in outside referenced Books for 6 different vendors. Some of them are calculated differently or involve finding the lowest cost-- its a pretty complicated build. Then those costs are summed up and averaged. That average is what is returned in E1.

Answer (score 0):

What is the formula in E1? Just use that as part of the formulas in column D, for example if E1 is something like =B1 and E4 is something like =E2/Sum(B:B) and you want to add 1 to it make D something like

```
=(B1/Sum(B:B))+1
```

Comment: Problem is that E1 is '=+AVERAGE(S18:S23)' and each of those is '=+IFERROR(Q18+R18,"")' and R18 and Q18 are very complicated and all these values are dynamically dependent on the Quantity and Product. There are also multiple VLOOKUPs and INDEXes between the Quantity/Product cells and the returned price.